# $F(x)=\int_0^\infty \frac{f(t)} {1+xt}dt$ is continuous and differentiable

Tags: real-analysis

> Assume that $f\in L^2 ([0,\infty))$. Define
> $F:(0,\infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ by $$ F(x)=\int_0^\infty f(t) /(1+xt)dt.
>  $$
> Prove that $F$ is continuous and differentiable.

I tried to use dominated convergence theorem by $f $ is not $L^1$. Also, I tried $$F(x)-F(x_0)=\int _0^\infty \frac{tf(t)(x-x_0)}{(1+xt)(1+x_0t)}dt$$ but I still can't see how the condition $f\in L^2$ can be used. can you give me some hint please?

Comment: Why do you need $f \in L^1$ to apply the dominated convergence theorem ? Remember the useful fact : to prove that $F$ is continuous on $(0, +\infty)$, it is sufficient to show that it is continuous on every $[a,b] \subset (0, +\infty)$. Remember also that $f \in L^2$ allows you to use Cauchy-Schwarz.

Comment: @TheSilverDoe I was thinking of  $f(t)/(1+xt)\leq f(t)$. If $f(t)\in L^1$ then I can apply dominated convergence. You just reminded me of inner products. I think here the continuity can be shown by the continuity of inner product, right?

Comment: Have you tried Cauchy Schwartz, on $f(t)$ and the remaining piece?

Comment: @AlexR Yeah I tried but I can't get a finite integral to get a term like $c|x-x_0|$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: For all $x,y \in [a,b]$,

$$|F(x) - F(y)| = |x-y|\left|\int_0^\infty \frac{tf(t)}{(1+xt)(1+yt)}\, dt\right|  \\\leqslant |x-y| \left(\int_0^\infty f^2(t) \, dt \right)^{1/2}  \left(\int_0^\infty \frac{t^2}{(1+at)^4} \, dt \right)^{1/2}$$